# How do I locate my new mySQL database where I want it?

Tags: mysql

I'm on Windows using mySQL Workbench when I absolutely have to, otherwise ADO.

I'm experienced with Jet databases where you just create your mdb file, put it wherever you want whenever you want, and open the database with an ADO connection string containing the path to the database.

Now I've got to do this wretched mySQL thing ... for some reason I don't understand there's this Data directory where all the databases go and you can't change that when creating the database(?).

So I create my database as a shell (1 junk table to be deleted later, no records) and it's stuck in this worthless Data directory. Now I want to copy/paste this shell to where I really want it, and start working on it through ADO to create my "real" database ... but it doesn't work; my ADO connection string contains the new path and the connection opens with no errors, but all operations only change the copy in the Data directory.

Yes I have searched this topic, and the only "solutions" I see are to change the default Data directory in the ini file ... this seems silly and unworkable; what if I want to create another database and put it somewhere else?

Can someone please shed some light here?

Comment: MySQL is a _database server_, that is something completely different compared to a _database file_. The database files you have experiences with can be compared to `sqlite` maybe. Those are also file based databases. A database _server_ on the other hand is different: it is a standalone process independent of your application of software. You only _use_ it, that means you do _not_ have to do any file system operations, that is nothing you are interested in anyway. You simply connect and use, and that at a performance that totally outruns _all_ file based database systems. It is another league.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you connect to the MySQL database as a user that can create databases, usually the `root` user after install, you can just write:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
```

and that database will be created on the machine that's running the MySQL server process in the `datadir` that MySQL is using. [There are default locations for these things](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation-layout.html), but you probably won't need to worry about them. You don't need to worry about where the files end up going as the first commenter says.

[Here is the information for finding your my.cnf file on Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). Once you find that file, update your `datadir` to the location that you want like this:

```
datadir="C:\New Data\Path"
```

and then stop your MySQL server and move your files. Restart the MySQL server after you copy all of the files in your current datadir to it. You can find your current `datadir` with the following command (connected to the server as the `root` user):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%datadir%';
```

**Make sure to stop the server before moving your files**.

The [CREATE TABLE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) shows that you can create a table in a `TABLESPACE` that's outside of your `datadir`. First create a tablespace like the following:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE my_tablespace ADD DATAFILE 'C:\my_space';
```

which needs to be a single file if you want to use the InnoDB engine. You can then create tables in that table space by specifying it in your table's creation like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (a INT) TABLESPACE my_tablespace;
```

I haven't done this before, but it should work.

Comment: Ok thanks for the responses, and please bear with my ignorance. I don't think I have any problem with the database creation - the result seems to be the same whether I create it with Workbench or CREATE DATABASE. The issue is that the files that make up the database seem to be stuck immovably in the default location, and these are terabyte databases which I planned to stick on 1 2TB drive for each database ... is there any way to do this using only one instance of mySQL server?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I already know how to do that (and I have done it for practice, so I know it works) ... but there is still only one default datadir so it doesn't address my problem (unless I'm missing something here). BTW I am editing my.ini, as I don't have a my.cnf.

Comment: Right, but I'm working with 2 or more databases that each have to be on different drives ... how can I do that when there is only one default directory?

Comment: That's what I need - either your solution exactly, or the symbolic link solution which I found while reading the documentation you pointed to. Thanks grizz!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to mark the answer as correct. Thanks